# How to make a function that subtracts a variable from another variable

Tags: c#, .net, math

So I want to make a function that when it is called it subtracts a variable from another variable sorry if I am not being clear i want to do something like this

```
int TreeHealth = 100;
int HitValue = 25;

Hit();
{
   TreeHealth - HitValue;
}
```

I tried doing that but it didn't work, so pls help.

Comment: Did you forget a return statement?

Comment: Side note: It is good idea to post code that at least look syntactically correct (unless your question about particular syntax error - but than it should include exact error message)... I.e. two open curly brace don't look very good...

Comment: Have you done any independent research on how to accomplish what you want? I bet you could have found the answer on the Internet in less time than it took you to write this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function to return your value, for sample:

```
int Hit() 
{
   return TreeHealth - HitValue;
}
```

In this case, `int` is the result of the `Hit` function.

### Using arguments

You also can pass arguments if you need:

```
int Hit(int tellHealth, int hitValue) 
{
   return tellHealth - hitValue;
}
```

The `int` type is the classic integer number, but there are other types you can work with `math` operations, such as `decimal`, `double`, `short`, `long`, etc.

Comment: Nice explanation, also 97% that OP is looking for just `TreeHealth -= HitValue`

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Hit()
{
    return TreeHealth - HitValue;
}
```